# Django with CherryPy - ModuleNotFound errors

Tags: python, django, cherrypy

I found [a gist](https://gist.github.com/nigma/4349257) that feasibly would allow me to integrate a CherryPy webserver into my program, and run a Django project via that CherryPy webserver. However I'm having some difficulties getting the thing to work properly.

Here's the Class in my code from the gist, largely unchanged

```
class ClientThread(object):
    HOST = "127.0.0.1"
    PORT = int("3852")
    DIR = "/home/user/project/"
    STATIC_ROOT = DIR + '/clientFiles/static/'

    def mount_static(self, url, root):
        """
        :param url: Relative url
        :param root: Path to static files root
        """
        config = {
            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': root,
            'tools.expires.on': True,
            'tools.expires.secs': 86400
        }
        cherrypy.tree.mount(None, url, {'/': config})

    def run(self):
        cherrypy.config.update({
            'server.socket_host': self.HOST,
            'server.socket_port': self.PORT,
            'engine.autoreload_on': False,
            'log.screen': True
        })

        self.mount_static(settings.STATIC_URL, self.STATIC_ROOT)

        cherrypy.tree.graft(WSGIHandler())
        cherrypy.engine.start()
        print("[Info]: Client started. Use http://{0}:{1} to access the WebApp.".format(self.HOST,self.PORT))
        cherrypy.engine.block()

    def init(self):
        print("[Info]: Starting Client WebApp...")
        cThread = Thread(target=self.run)
        cThread.start()
```

This entire class is initiated via `ClientThread().init()`

The first few lines of the gist at the top of my app (in order):

```
import os
from threading import Timer
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "clientFiles.settings"
import django
django.setup()
import cherrypy
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
```

My project is laid out like this:

```
.
├── clientFiles
│   ├── clientFiles
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │   └── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── static
├── main.py
```

I initiated my Django project in the root directory with `django-admin startproject clientFiles`.

When I try to run my program I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clientFiles.settings'
```

It appears like it's a Module loading issue, right?

So I tried changing `os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "clientFiles.settings"` to `os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "clientFiles.clientFiles.settings"` because my Django urls is in clientFiles/clientFiles

After doing that, my app starting up indicates the CherryPy starting without issues:

```
[24/Dec/2020:04:37:14] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[24/Dec/2020:04:37:14] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[24/Dec/2020:04:37:14] ENGINE Serving on http://127.0.0.1:3852
[24/Dec/2020:04:37:14] ENGINE Bus STARTED
[Info]: Client started. Use http://127.0.0.1:3852 to access the WebApp.
```

But when I try to access the site at http://127.0.0.1:3852 I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /

No module named 'clientFiles.urls'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:3852/
Django Version:     3.1.4
Exception Type:     ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    

No module named 'clientFiles.urls'

Exception Location:     <frozen importlib._bootstrap>, line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/user/project',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 24 Dec 2020 04:38:14 +0000
```

And in the console I get:

```
> Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 165, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 288, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 545, in resolve
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clientFiles.urls'
```

OK, so perhaps an issue with the directory structure....

I move the contents of clientFiles/clientFiles into clientFiles so I have this:

```
.
├── clientFiles
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── main.py
```

Aha! Startup success. I see the Welcome to Django page.

BUT, when I try to create a new app for logging in or something...

`python3 manage.py startapp login`

In the clientFiles directory I now have

```
.
├── asgi.py
├── __init__.py
├── login
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── urls.cpython-37.pyc
├── settings.py
├── static
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

And just simply following the tutorial here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/

I've created the view, created the urls.py in the login app, and inserted the following into clientFiles/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', include('login.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Run the program...started up fine. But when I try to browse anywhere on my http://127.0.0.1:3852 I now get

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /

No module named 'login'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:3852/
Django Version:     3.1.4
Exception Type:     ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    

No module named 'login'

Exception Location:     <frozen importlib._bootstrap>, line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/user/project',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 24 Dec 2020 04:55:22 +0000
```

And here's where I'm stuck. I've tried modifiying paths left and right, directory structure, adding extra mounts for CherryPy for the new directories...I'm at a loss.

If you have any ideas that would be greatly appreciated...or if perhaps there's a different way I can integrate a webserver into my app capable of serving dynamic & static content via django or perhaps Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was pretty simple to solve. I simply recreated the root of my app into a Django project and then copied my main.py to the project. Done!